# Create a text file on Azure using Scala

Tags: scala, azure, blob

I have the following piece of scala code that will write text to a txt file sitting locally.

```
// PrintWriter
import java.io._
val pw = new PrintWriter(new File("resources/myfile.txt"))
pw.write("Test text")
pw.close
```

How do i get this to work on azure blob storage?

I have tried:

```
val pw = new PrintWriter(new File("wasb://[my container name]@[My Storage account].blob.core.windows.net/resources/myfile.txt"))
```

But it doesn't work. 
What am i doing wrong? By the way, for the sake of this example, I'm keeping it simple. In reality, I am outputting more meaningful data.

Thanks

Con

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a file on Azure blog storage using the java.io or nio package. You need to use their REST API or their SDK.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-file

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-java-how-to-use-blob-storage